# Count 1-10 in 1 sec intervals and print in div class box

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I've recently completed an evaluation on a jsfiddle and completed it but probably not in the way they asked. I attempted a for loop to begin with but could not get anything print initially and tested different environments. When I finally did get it to print, it would only print the last number rather the numbers 1-10. This was my solution to printing it but not listing them out. What would be your approach to listing them out? in the Div class box provided when a button is pressed to initiate it.

https://jsfiddle.net/vjoehmq6/

```
    function change(){

function count(num) {
    if(!num)
        num = 1;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
        x[0].innerHTML = num;     

    if(num < 10) {
        setTimeout(function() { count(num + 1); }, 1000);
   }
}
    setTimeout(count, 1000);

}
```

Comment: It looks like your code works... What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: A different method that lists out the numbers 1-10, I had attempted a for loop to list it out but it would only print the last number repeatedly at 1 second intervals.

Comment: If you're looking for an alternate solution to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/j22g8pkk/

Comment: oh I like that! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to append text vertically**

`x[0].innerHTML += '<br>'+num;`

Comment: That is incorrect in two ways.
First, it would actually be `x[0].innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML + str;`
Second, adding `'<br>'` doesn't insert  line break. Rather, you need to do:
`x[0].innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML + "\A"+num;`
`x[0].innerHTML.style.whiteSpace = "pre";`

Comment: Your points are all very valid, except not really because my solution works. Try running it in the fiddle, before trying to bash on my answer.

Comment: @RobertI My apologies, just tested and your method works fine from file. I was thinking of a different post involving some flexboxes and nested `<div>`s among other things that were refusing to interpret `<br>` elements properly from `.innerHTML` assignment calls.

Comment: There is no reason to expand out that expression. `+=` is the prefered method. @GameGibu

Comment: odd... that does work. In the past, `element.innerHTML += "foobar";` has returned errors or overwritten the content. This new behaviour is unexpected but welcome.